Usage of "may" as a model auxillary verb and whatnot
This question is about this sentence:

May he die a miserable death.

Generally speaking, this sentence is understood as a question involving the auxiliary verb may — that is, a question asking permission.
So, it can be rewritten with proper punctuation marks:

"May he die a miserable death?"

Besides, this sentence can also be used to declare or express somebody's wish (an optative subjunctive, methinks).
With the punctuation marks(?) again,

"May he die a miserable death"!.

(May the lord smile on you (Bible)/ may you long live are also the sentences
of same grammatical construction above.)
For the both contexts, the grammatical
construct is apparently the same. Without proper punctuation marks, it is obviously hard to tell the contextual meanings in the written forms apart.
With the fact that mostly we have unique grammatical structures for different contexts in English, I personally see it as a shortcoming in English grammar.But,I just want to verify the truth behind this thought.
If one argues that it is perfectly grammatical to use the very same structure to express wishes, then why can't we normally replace the verb may with might let?  For example, is it acceptable to say "Let he die miserable death"?

What does "both purposes" refer to? "Besides" what?

You seem to have left out part of the question. You're suggesting that there are two possible interpretations of the sentence, but only described one of them: it expresses a wish. What's the other?

Asking permission:- May he die a miserable death?

Speakers wish:- May he die a miserable death!

That should be in the question. As you say, we distinguish it with the question mark. And in speech, we use intonation.

Questions are indicated by raising pitch at the end.

Well... "You go to the shop" raising pitch this  can also be changed into a question. but you have a grammatical construct for question:- do you go to the shop? Likewise, why don't we have a different construct to express wishes?

We have a general way to turn any statement into a question: "Is it true that he may die a miserable death?"

That is an extended way ofsaying! Rather, I wonder why a different grammatical aspect didn't evolve to express wishes @ do grammararians consider it permisible,?. Moreover, we can't always rely on intonation and pitch changing

"I see it as a shortcoming in English grammar." I see it as economy.

There's nothing unique about this. Some languages, such as Italian, differentiate yes/no questions from statements primarily by pitch (and punctuation of course, when written). Some have the same verb form for imperative as for some form of the indicative. And all languages have some ambiguity. I don't think I've ever encountered a situation where this ambiguity would be a problem and the "May he...!" construction is not a common one. You might as well complain about witch and which sounding the same.

I question whether “May he die a miserable death?” is acceptable for the meaning “Is it possible that he will die a miserable death?”  What is it supposed to mean?

Please note that your “I see it as a shortcoming in English grammar. How do you see it?” is off-topic for this site. SE is for questions with factual answers; it’s not a discussion board. So requests for opinions are out of place here.


With the fact that mostly we have unique grammatical structures for different contexts in English, I see it as a shortcoming in English grammar. How do you see it?

I agree that it's something of a shortcoming (could be ambiguous, although in practice not really a problem), but I disagree that "mostly we have unique grammatical structures for different contexts in English". English doesn't do as comprehensive a job at grammatically marking of moods & modalities as some other languages. For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortative points out that the sentence "Let us go." can be either imperative or cohortative. There are many such cases.
